# BST node deletion

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am reading the book of "Data structures and algorithm analysis in Java-Person (2012), Mark Allen Weiss".

The code for delete node in BST

```
  /**
     * Internal method to remove from a subtree.
     * @param x the item to remove.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return the new root of the subtree.
     */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> remove( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return t;   // Item not found; do nothing

        int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

        if( compareResult < 0 )
            t.left = remove( x, t.left );
        else if( compareResult > 0 )
            t.right = remove( x, t.right );
        else if( t.left != null && t.right != null ) // Two children
        {
            t.element = findMin( t.right ).element;
            t.right = remove( t.element, t.right );
        }
        else
            t = ( t.left != null ) ? t.left : t.right;
        return t;
    }
    /**
     * Internal method to find the smallest item in a subtree.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return node containing the smallest item.
     */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return null;
        else if( t.left == null )
            return t;
        return findMin( t.left );
    }
```

I understand that the general method for deleting a node is to replace the value of deleting node by the minimum value on the right side.

My question is that what is "else statement" for? 
For example,

```
       13
      /  \
     8   14
    / \ 
   6   11
      /  \
     9    12
```

if I wish to remove 8, the first step should be replaced by 9

```
       13
      /  \
     9   14
    / \ 
   6   11
      /  \
     9    12
```

and then find 9 in the leaf of 11 and set it null,

```
       13
      /  \
     9   14
    / \ 
   6   11
      /  \
     null 12
```

So I don't understand why it is

```
else
     t = ( t.left != null ) ? t.left : t.right;
```

rather than

```
else 
     t = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That else statement you are mentioning is meant to be executed for the case that a node has only one children (since the if else statement that is meant for the two-children case won't be evaluated to true).

As a result, here you want to assign the non-Null node, so you do:

```
t = ( t.left != null ) ? t.left : t.right;
```

which says that if left is not `null`, then assign left to `t`, else assign right to `t`. Here we know that we have exactly one child, thus only left or right will be not null.

So if we did:

```
t = null;
```

that would be wrong.